# Check logical constraints through SQL nested references

Tags: sql

Let a SQL schema with 4 tables and nested references

For example modeling a restaurant, with a different menu every weekday, and some customer who have booked a table for one day and want to order a meal :

```
                             +------+
                             | days |
                             +----------+
                             | day      |
                             +----------+
                             | friday   |
                             | saturday |
                             | sunday   |
                             +----------+
                           ┐              ┌
+-------+                 /                \
| meals |                                    +-----------+
+------------+----------+                    | customers |
| meal       | day (*)  |                    +----------+---------+
+------------+----------+                    | customer | day (*) |
| pizza      | friday   |                    +----------+---------+
| tacos      | friday   |                    | Joe      | friday  |
| chicken    | saturday |                    | Alice    | sunday  |
| fish&chips | sunday   |                    | Oscar    | sunday  |
| paella     | sunday   |                    +----------+---------+
+------------+----------+                   

                    ┌                           ┐
                     \                         /
                       +--------+
                       | orders |
                       +--------------+----------+
                       | customer (*) | meal (*) |
                       +--------------+----------+
                       | Joe          | pizza    |
                       | Oscar        | paella   |
                       +--------------+----------+
```

(Foreign keys are marked with (*), and I tried to express references with arrows)

I want to prevent Alice from ordering some chicken, since she is planned on sunday, and chicken is planned on saturday.

In other words, for each record in orders,

- orders.meal refers to a record of meals, and meals.day refers to a record of days
- orders.customer refers to a record of customers, and customers.day refers to a record of days
- and the days referred to must be the same.

Is there any SQL-way to check this constraint at INSERT / UPDATE ?

Comment: "Is there any SQL-way to check this constraint at INSERT / UPDATE ?" - there is, but it would require a redesign of your schema - otherwise assuming your RDBMS does not have **immutable columns** (because no ISO SQL-compliant RDBMS does at-present) you cannot have an invariant `CHECK CONSTRAINT` in one table that enforces constraints on data in another table - such is a limitation of ISO SQL's DML (SQL is awful, but SQL-based RDBMS are the _least awful_ systems we have as of 2020 - And NoSQL-approaches are _even worse_).

Comment: "Is there any SQL-way to check this constraint at INSERT / UPDATE ?" - the alternative approach is by using a `TRIGGER` to implement a _one-time_ **non-invariant** "constraint" (quotes used intentionally) because this will not be invariant, which defeats the point of it being a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is declare "super keys" in your `meals` and `customers` tables, a key declared across both the `meal`/`customer` column *and* the `day` column.

That makes those pairs of columns valid references for a foreign key constraint. In turn, that then means that you can add the `day` column to the `orders` table and include `day` in your foreign key references.

If needs be, one can then declare a view over the `orders` table to conceal the `day` column, and make that view, rather than the orders table, be the way that applications interact with the database, closely mimicking your existing structure. The only complexity is in populating the `day` column during `insert` and `update`. One way to deal with that is via triggers on the view.